# Email alert designed using SharePoint Designer doesnt display image

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I created an email alert workflow in SharePoint 2010 using SharePoint Designer.

This email alert has images embedded in them using the HTML tag .

When i receive the email alert,it doesn't load in Outlook and also in mobile(Iphone).

Can someone help?

Comment: How are you referencing the image in the HTML part of the email?

Comment: I'm using <img src="https://imageURL"/> in the body section

Comment: Did this ever get resolved...I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Hi @TimWelsh,the email images got displayed in webmail but in outlook it didn't display for reasons unknown(may be since I was in VPN). IPhone issue was because of some security issues. When i used a image from google,IPhone displayed the image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you might be having, is that your image is stored locally on the computer you are using.  Know that when you create workflows and send emails, it is running on the server farm.  So unless the image is also stored on your server, it will not appear in the email address, as the server cannot reference that image.

Try putting the picture into your sharepoint site, and reference the picture using the path along your sharepoint site from the workflow.

Comment: Hi Brandon,sorry I was not clear..I uploaded the image to the picture library and used that URL inside <img src>

Comment: Are you including it in the email itself?  If you want to add HTML elements to an email, fist build the <img> as a dynamic string, and set it as a workflow variable.  Then perform a lookup on that variable in the email itself.

Comment: Hi Brandon..Yeah did the same. Also i see that these images are loading fine in OWA. But not in outlook and mobile. All users have access to the image location .

Comment: Can you post an example of the whole image URL source?  You don'T have to actually give details, just descriptions, like masterpage/sites/mySite/images/myimage.jpg

Comment: <img src="https://sitecollectionURL/sites/May20/Pics/EIS-ITALert%20Header.jpg" width="627" height="151" alt=""/>

Comment: What I would recommend, is to test this, write the alt attribute as alt="Error text".  This way, if the image doesn't load, but the tag is working as it should, you will see the error text in the email.  That way, youknow you are referencing your picture incorrectly.  IF no text appears, then it is your html declaration that is incorrect

Comment: I see the text "Error Text" in place of the image..

Comment: Then the image reference is wrong.  Are you using https:// in front of the URL as well?  Also, try renaming the file with no spaces.  The %20 has been known to cause trouble when performing lookups.

Comment: Yes,I'm using https:// in front of the URL(but its not getting displayed in this site). I will re-upload the pics file with a different name and try :)